# Stunning Fist in a 1 vs. 1; is the stun only for the target's turn?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

[Stunning Fist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/stunning-fist-combat---final) states:

> A defender who fails this saving throw is stunned for 1 round (until just before your next turn).

So, in a 1 vs. 1 battle, and assuming you went 1<sup>st</sup> in initiative and using stunning fist, would your opponent only be stunned on his turn? Since his turn is "right before your next turn," am I interpreting it correctly?

Answer (score 5):

"right before your turn" means *right* before your turn; that is-- *after* his turn but before yours.  No time passes between him being unstunned and your turn starting.

If you have ever played Magic: the Gathering it's kind of like something happening after EOT of the turn before yours, but before your untap step.  It's not in *anyone's* turn.

Answer (score 3):

> A defender who fails this saving throw is stunned for 1 round (until just before your next turn).

Here, "your" refers to the person with the Stunning Fist ability - the attacker, not the defender.  The defender is stunned from when the attacker stuns them until right before the attacker's next turn, which means that the defender's turn between those two is lost.

Your "turn" is the time in the initiative order you act. If the attacker goes on initiative count 12 and stuns the defender, and the defender goes later in that round on initiative count 8 - or had acted earlier and would go on initiative count 23 the next round - they are stunned at that time, until initiative count 12 comes around again. The stun is gone at the interval between count 13 and count 12. Therefore, they were stunned for an entire round but are not stunned during the attacker's next turn.

In any event, the power works as intended, the person stunned loses their action and the attacker will get the next action (in a 1 vs. 1 fight).